# Let $A$ be a subset. If $A$ is non-empty, then $A$ has at least two subsets. Specifically, $\emptyset$ $\subseteq A$ and $A \subseteq A$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Still new to proofs so walking through this step-by-step.

Claim: If $A$ is a non-empty, then $A$ has at least two subsets. Specifically, $\emptyset$ $\subseteq A$ and $A \subseteq A$.

Proving the contrapositive.

If $A$ has less than two subsets, then $A$ is empty.

Would that just imply that $\emptyset \subseteq A$, which means that the empty set is the only set in $A$?

I know I haven't provided much, but I just need a push in the right direction. Still brand new to elementary set-theory.

Comment: No, just argue directly.

Comment: We always have $\emptyset \subseteq A$ and $A \subseteq A$. If $A$ has only 1 subset, then $A = \emptyset$.

Answer (score 1):

If A is empty, then A does not have two subsets.

Thus, if A has two subsets, A is not empty.

Comment: This is the *converse* of what the OP is trying to prove.